# Why does this partial differential solution not work?

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

Here I am trying to solve a simple partial differential equation i.e. $ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=6y
$ but for some reason it won't solve it. There clearly is a solution as shown in the bottom and the code gives me a perfectly valid solution if I replace 6y with 0. Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: This is an elliptic PDE and it as infinitely many solutions. You need some boundary conditions or something the like to make the solution unique.

Comment: how can I tell mathematica to only give me polynomial solutions?

Comment: Make an ansatz and compare coefficients. See, e.g., `CoefficientRules`.

Comment: What is an ansatz?

Comment: `DSolve[]'s` support for PDE is still somewhat limited,
 so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: The Try suggestion is wrong, because you first solve the pde with "constant z"(concerning independent  variables x,y) and later substitute the constant z by 6y!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz

Comment: @UlrichNeumann ops.. Yes You are right.I deleted that comment.

Comment: Please post the code text rather than the screenshot of it so people can easily test and improve your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 3;
coeffs = Flatten[Table[c[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]];
ansatz = Sum[c[i, j] x^i y^j, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}];
result = ansatz /. 
   Solve[Flatten[
       CoefficientList[
        D[ansatz, x, x] + D[ansatz, y, y] - y, {x, y}]] == 0, 
     coeffs][[1]]
```

> c[0, 0] + y c[0, 1] - x^2 c[0, 2] + y^2 c[0, 2] +   x^2 y (1/2 - 3 c[0, 3]) + y^3 c[0, 3] + x c[1, 0] + x y c[1, 1] -   1/3 x^3 c[1, 2] + x y^2 c[1, 2] - x^3 y c[1, 3] + x y^3 c[1, 3]

A test:

```
D[result, x, x] + D[result, y, y] // Simplify
```

> y

You see, there are plenty solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica can solve this pde :

```
DSolve[Derivative[2, 0][g][x, y] + Derivative[0, 2][g][x, y] ==0, g, {x, y}]
(* {{g -> Function[{x, y}, C[1][I x + y] + C[2][-I x + y]]}} *)
```

The solution of your problem is f[x,y]=g[x,y]+y^3 !

Comment: Yes, I noted this in my question as well.